# How to use different unit in shapes?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I need to draw a 15cm shape using Photoshop CS4 my document rules are set to mm/cm, but despite this, the shape is still using px.

How can I draw a 15cm square without sliding the mouse to the exact mm (it is rounding to 5mm +/-) I need an exact measure for this shape.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Just click on the document with the **Rectangle Shape Tool** and write down the
  size : 15 cm
- or when the shape it is done, do the same at the **Properties Panel**

[image: square]

Comment: thanks! was looking for a switch. while editing I noticed right-click also set the measure but your solution is faster <3